# Default Salesforce pgination

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I want to add default alphabetic pagination to my VF page but I didn't found how to do it, can anyone help me please !

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [**`<apex:enhancedlist>`**](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) component.

Here's an example from the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_compref_enhancedList.htm):

```
<apex:enhancedList type="Account" height="300" rowsPerPage="10" id="AccountList" />
```